# How to add the ath10k_pci module at the startup?

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I am having 100Mbps of speed over a 5GHz network and 50Mbps over a 2.4GHz network. But when I start the system, I get 25-30Mbps of speed over the 5GHz network while I am getting 50Mbps over the 2.4GHz.

Every time I have to use the following commands to get the full speed by removing and adding the **ath10k_pci**:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

These commands disconnect the internet for 15-20 seconds but after the WiFi is connected again, I am getting full speed.

Is there any way to add this module automatically to every startup to avoid manual efforts?

Comment: Try this instead `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service`  See if wifi works better with power management off

Comment: I have already set the power mode for the best performance. Do I still need to use these commands?

Comment: Check `iwconfig` before running your command at startup, if it shows power management as on, it will cause problems with the driver